# Android: findViewById NullpointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, imageview

My problem is the imageView will be null in `showPicture()`. I call this method from an other thread.
If I remove the *`if (imageView != null)`*... condition, I will get a `NullPointerException`. Can you tell my Why? Thanks.

Activity java file:

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.p1);         //IT WORKS
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.client, menu);
    return true;
}

public void showPicture(final int ID) {
    if (imageView != null) {
        imageView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.setImageResource(ID);

            }
        });
    } else {        // It will be executed.
        System.out.println("WHY imageView IS NULL?!");
    }
}
```

Layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in strings.xml:

```
<string name="content">image</string>
```

Comment: Where you called `showPicture(......)` ?

Comment: Its depends on How are you calling `showPicture()`??

Comment: Possibly you're instantiating the activity on your own with `new`. Don't do that.

Comment: Where and how you are calling `showPicture()`??

Comment: My program manage a socket based communication. When the client connect to the server socket this ClientActivity will be started:
 clientActivity = new ClientActivity();
 Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, clientActivity.getClass());
mainActivity.startActivity(intent);

After this I will call showPicture(..);

Comment: where you are calling showPicture() method, Can you post that code also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My program manage a socket based communication. When the client connect to the server socket this ClientActivity will be started: clientActivity = new ClientActivity(); Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, clientActivity.getClass());

Never instantiate activities with `new`. Either the classes should not be activities in the first place, or you should invoke them with an `Intent`.

The reason for the NPE is that `onCreate()` was not called on the activity you created yourself.

Comment: Now I understand what caused the error. I modified my code and it works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

```
    setContentView(R.layout.client);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.p1);

    //after this use function show picture
    showPicture(id);
```

you have to call your function after `setContentView` because after `setContentView layout content initialize.`